# Auto Generating Classes for tables without any xml files

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, hibernate-4.x

I have a DB with around 50+ tables. I plan to use spring-boot(1.2.4) with hibernate 4.3.10.Final and Java8 in my new project. Using Eclipse Luna SR2 as my IDE.

If i generate classes for tables using hibernate tool, they generate Classes and also *.hbm.xml. However, i do not want to use any kind of xml file in my project (one of the reasons i picked spring boot). If i want to use JPA annotations, do i need to write each and every class by myself? Is there any way i can generate classes with annotations without any xml files?

Is it possible?

Comment: is it possible to use netbeans? I am not familiar with eclipse, but netbeans has a feature to create entities from database connection and uses only standard jpa annotations that can be configured at the start of the proces (fetch types, mappings...). No xml files are created. But it is not automated, you need to invoke the process

Comment: @Zavael: IDE is not a problem. I can use netbeans also if it have this facility. Can you please describe how i can do that? If it works, i will use Netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In netbeans ide (version 8+ in my case) you right click on the package where you want to generate the entities. 
Select `New -> Other` and from Categories choose `Persistence -> Entity Classes from Database`.
From database connection in the wizard you can create `New database connection..` and follow the wizard to create the connection.

After that you will see some Available tables that you can choose from to generate the java classes.

I generate the classes often so every time I need to uncheck the `Create Persistence unit` because I already have one.
I used to uncheck the `Use Column Names in Relationships` because I dont like the naming `customerId` of sssociated entity variable Customer. When I uncheck that option the variable looks like `private Customer customer;`

Than click finish and you should have your entities with jpa annotations and named queries. Play around with the options as suits you. Than you can swich back to eclipse :)

Here is the process [tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html#creating-entity)

Comment: I just saw that you can generate in eclipse also. But we need to create a JPA project.